# Creating a file template?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I have about 20 lines of text that needs to have some values in it replaced when I use `createFileAtPath`

e.g.

```
[firstname] has a surname of [surname]
and is [gender]
etc etc etc
etc etc etc
etc etc etc
etc etc etc
and lives in [suburb]
```

I have to create this file a number of times when a user clicks a button

Can this be done by creating some sort of template or constant where I can replace the placeholders with my variables? Something similar to `NSString stringWithFormat` called like

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:myTemplate, person.firstname, person.surname, person.gender, person.suburb]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at NSRegularExpression - replaceMatchesInString:options:range:withTemplate:. You can match something in a NSMutableString and replace it.